# Infinite sequencing number generator not work in python?

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to implement a nature number generator which can generator infinite numbers, my code:

```
def nature():
    s = 0
    while True:
        yield s
        s += 1
```

when I use `next(nature())`, I get a sequence of 0s, why this? and how to fix it?

```
>>> next(nature())
0
>>> next(nature())
0
>>> next(nature())
0
>>> next(nature())
0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you call `nature()` you create a new generator.
Instead do this:

```
n = nature()
next(n)
next(n)
next(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a new generator every time you recall it like so; so it starts from the initial value. What you want is:

```
>>> n = nature()
>>> next(n)
0
>>> next(n)
1
>>> next(n)
2
>>> next(n)
3
```

Comment: There's no "restarting" the generator.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new generator each time, try creating it once and passing it to each next call

Answer (score 0):

Don't instance your generator over and over, for example, instance one and use it several times like this:

```
def nature():
    s = 0
    while True:
        yield s
        s += 1

n = nature()
for i in range(10):
    print next(n)

print "Doing another stuff... Resuming the counting"

for i in range(10):
    print next(n)
```